# Angularjs Scope variables duplicate values

Tags: angularjs

Not fully understanding my scope issue here in angular and looking for clarity and how to fix this issue.  I have an array of strings that I get from a service.  What I'm trying to do is store those strings in one scope variable.

When my `ui-select="loadDealStuff($item)"` is run I have a on-select method that passes the selected object in.  If the key of that is a certain value then i'm removing some elements from my array.  Other wise if its not then I need the original values from the array.  Here is the code:

```
scope.productTypes = myService.constantsStrings.myProductTypes;                
scope.otherTypes = myService.constantsStrings.myProductTypes;

var x = scope.productTypes;//array I want to manipulate
var y = scope.otherTypes;//should be original values

scope.loadDealStuff= function(item){
  if(item.key == 3){                                                                        
    x.splice(0,1);
    x.splice(2,1);
    console.log(x);
  } else {                                                                
    console.log(y);
  }
};
```

When logged y is the same as x.

Comment: Both `scope.productTypes` and `scope.otherTypes` have a reference to the same array (the result of your service), by extension then both 'x' and 'y' are referencing the same array as well, since you're assigning the reference of `scope.productTypes` and `scope.otherTypes` respectively. 
You'd have to create a copy of the array instead of assigning it. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript) for more information.

Comment: angular.copy your stuff.